# How to use Lambda expressions in java for nested if-else and for loop together

Tags: selenium, if-statement, lambda, foreach, java-8

I have following Code where i will receive list of `names` as parameter.In the loop, first i'm assigning index 0 value from list to local variable `name`. There after comparing next values from list with `name`. If we receive any non-equal value from list, i'm assigning value of `result` as 1 and failing the test case.

Below is the Array list

```
List<String> names= new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("John");
names.add("Mark");
```

Below is my selenium test method

```
 public void test(List<String> names)
        String name=null;   
        int a=0;

        for(String value:names){
          if(name==null){
             System.out.println("Value is null");
             name=value;
          }
         else if(name.equals(value)){
             System.out.println("Received Same name");
             name=value;
             }
         else{
              a=1;
              Assert.fail("Received different name in between");
          }
         }
```

How can i convert above code into lambda expressions?. I'm using cucumber data model, hence i receive data as list from feature file. Since i can't give clear explanation, just posted the example logic i need to convert to lambda expression.

Comment: I can't understand your question: you have a list of names which is your input. Then you need to compare that list with what? I can't understand your expected output.
The first name of the list (in this case **John**) should respect which rule? Can you please provide an additional example?

Comment: @Leviand I need to validate whether all values in the list are same. So i took one local varible `name` initially which is null. For the first time, retrieved names(0) value and assigned to the name. Later on comparing the remaining values from list with `name` .

Comment: So basically your list should be full of **John** for being correct?

Comment: @Leviand Yes, that's correct. If we pass any other name in between, test case should fail.

Comment: Ok, I've posted the answer, looks if it's fine :)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `a` variables in your method?

Comment: @Holger I have some requirement in my project to do so. Since i can't add that code, created sample example and posted

Comment: But since `Assert.fail` will throw, the `a` will not be in scope afterwards, making the entire assignment pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution: it cycles all element in your list checking if are all the same.
You can try adding or editing the list so you can have different outputs. I've written the logic, you can easly put it into a JUnit test

```
    List<String> names= new ArrayList<>();
    names.add("John");
    names.add("Mark");

    String firstEntry = names.get(0);
    boolean allMatch = names.stream().allMatch(name -> firstEntry.equals(name));
    System.out.println("All names are the same: "+allMatch);
```

Comment: @eduPeeth was that ok?

Comment: Or without intermediate variable: `boolean allMatch = names.stream().allMatch(Predicate.isEqual(names.get(0)));`, though I would perhaps use `boolean allMatch = names.equals(Collections.nCopies(names.size(), names.get(0)));`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for duplicates, whenever you have distinct value , set a=1 and say assert to fail. You can achieve this by :

```
List<String> names= new ArrayList<String>();
        names.add("John");
        names.add("Mark");

        if (names.stream().distinct().limit(2).count() > 1) {
            a= 1,
            Assert.fail("Received different name in between");      

        } else {
        System.out.println("Received Same name");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply eduPeeth. It helpes, but need above logic in forEach as i need to apply same logic in my code.

Comment: Cool. Hope you get the approach , you can fit it as per your requirement.

Comment: Don’t call toArray() only to discard it by calling the length property. Instead use the count() terminal operation.

Comment: @Aominè or `limit(2).count() > 1`, to stop counting when more than one have been detected already.

Comment: @Holger  and Aomine - I have updated the answer as per your suggestions. Thanks for valued suggestions.